# Connect the two created markdown and image nodes to original one

Tags: gatsby

Hi I have a Graph_page nodes and it has two fields `image` and `body`. Image is the image path from which I create remoteAsset so that Image CDN works, I do the same with `body` so that it can be parsed by remark.

But for the love of God I can't figure out how to connect those two nodes per Graph_page so tha I can query it.

```
export const onCreateNode: GatsbyNode["onCreateNode"] = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  createNodeId,
  createContentDigest,
}) => {
  if (node.internal.type === "Graph_pages") {
    const nodeId = `MarkdownNode:${createNodeId(`${node.id}-body`)}`;
    const mdNode = {
      id: nodeId,
      parent: node.id,
      internal: {
        type: `MarkdownNode`,
        mediaType: "text/markdown",
        content: he.decode(node["body"]),
        contentDigest: `contentDigest`,
      },
    };
    createNode(mdNode);

    const pathname = new URL(node.image).pathname;
    const fileNameWithExtension = path.basename(pathname);
    const extension = path.extname(fileNameWithExtension);
    const fileNameWithoutExtension = path.basename(
      fileNameWithExtension,
      extension
    );
    const imageAttr = await probe(node.image);
    const imageData = {
      url: `https://XXXXX.netlify.app/.netlify/images?url=${node.image}`,
      placeholderUrl: `https://XXXXX.netlify.app/.netlify/images?url=${node.image}&w=%width%&h=%height%`,
      mimeType: imageAttr.mime,
      filename: fileNameWithoutExtension,
      width: imageAttr.width,
      height: imageAttr.height,
      alt: `Red and rosa infinity thingy floating in air`,
    };
    const assetId = `ImageAsset:${createNodeId(`${node.id}-image`)}`;
    createNode({
      ...imageData,
      id: assetId,
      parent: node.id,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: `ImageAsset`,
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(imageData),
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to reverse the order of creating `ImageAsset` and `MarkdownNode` nodes. in this way you will able to include the `ImageAsset` node id in the `MarkdownNode` as `imageAssetId`. In addition you can implement  resolver with `createResolvers` [API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/#createresolvers-api). Something like:

```
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  const resolvers = {
    MarkdownNode: {
      imageAsset: {
        type: "ImageAsset",
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          return context.nodeModel.getNodeById({
            id: source.imageAssetId,
            type: "ImageAsset",
          })
        },
      },
    },
  }
  createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```